# How can I group items in Python by the value of a single field?

Tags: python

I've got a set of data that contains, a username, email address, and location.

Although the username will be different some of the usernames will have the same email address as the owner.

Now im trying to work out some logic to be able to group all the usersnames with the same email address. All of the usernames with the same email address will be sent an email containing all usersnames.

Usersnames with different email addresses will get an individual email.

I went down the following route as far as logic goes but it doesnt work as well as id like (it doesnt add all users needed in `same_email`). Any advise on the best approach would be appreciated.

```
emails = []
same_email = []
not_same = []
for data in user_list:
    email = data[2]
    if email not in emails:
        emails.append(email)
    elif email in emails:
        same_email.append(data)
    for email_d in same_email:
        if email not in email_d[2]:
            not_same.append((data,))
```

Comment: use dictionary with email as key and list of usernames as value.

Comment: To add to @AjaySingh comment, look at the `collections.defaultdict` constructor to directly create a dict with list as values

Comment: The title of a question on StackOverflow should be *specific to that question*, enough that someone who's having trouble can tell if a specific question's answers are likely to help them just by looking at the title. I've tried to edit to meet that criteria.

Comment: By the way -- is each value of `data` a list, or a tuple? (Tuples, because they're immutable indexed objects, are easier to work with here).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to easily bucket your items, then iterate through that dictionary when it's complete.

A [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), by contrast, is the best structure to use for an unordered group of items -- such as the set of email addresses with only one account. Here, we're using one set (`regular_email_addresses`) for all email addresses tied only to a single account, and then another set per email address to store the account datums tied to same.

```
import collections

# whenever a lookup is done in this dict, and no entry already exists, call set() to
# create the new, default entry.
userdata_by_email = collections.defaultdict(set)

for data in user_list:
    email = data[2]
    # add always works here, because defaultdict is creating a new set
    userdata_by_email[email].add(tuple(data)) # data can't be a list here, so cast to tuple

regular_email_addresses = set()
for email, userdata_set in userdata_by_email.iteritems():
    if len(userdata_set) == 1:
        regular_email_addresses.add(email)
    else:
        send_special_email(email, userdata_set)

send_bulk_email(regular_email_addresses)
```

Fill in your own implementation of `send_special_email` (to send an email to a single address with multiple usernames) and `send_bulk_email` (to send an email to all the addresses with only one username), and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases using the functions provided by the language, is better than coming with your own implementation

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) initialises the elements of a dict with the provided type. `list` in your case

[groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can be used to group any iteratable based on a key value

sample implementation below.

```
import itertools,collections

data = [('a','some_data','a@gmail.com'),
    ('aa','some_data','a@gmail.com'),
    ('b','some_data','b@gmail.com')]

email_group = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[2]):
    email_group[k] = list(v)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(list,
        {'a@gmail.com': [('a', 'some_data', 'a@gmail.com'),
          ('aa', 'some_data', 'a@gmail.com')],
         'b@gmail.com': [('b', 'some_data', 'b@gmail.com')]})
```